# How to generate 0 and 1 matrix based on conditions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am doing a scheduling task. I translate the problem to generate an 8*8 matrix with 0 and 1 in it such that each row sums to 1 and each column sums to as close to 1 as possible.

The columns are actually a day divided into 8 pieces. Rows are the days. And 0 and 1 represent two tasks.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: Sounds like your making binary soduko, if this is your intention https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-set-7-suduku/ you can generate a solution that satisfies your needs as you continue to add elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an identity matrix and then simply re-order the rows.

[image]

If your matrix is Not NxN then you apply same rules to the largest NxN portion of it and then continue by wrapping the identity function from top-to-bottom, and right-to-left.  You are free to swap rows within the NxN portion to redistribute the active hours of the task. In this example columns G and H are outliers...you are free to swap the cells in G and H rows 1 and 2 with any of the other G and H  cells rows 3,4,5 and 6.

[image]

In this example rows 7 and 8 are the outliers... you are free to swap cells in 7 and 8 columns A and B with any of the other cells in rows 7 and 8 columns C,D,E and F.

[image]

Comment: Very Very Genius! Do you have idea if it is not n*n matrix?

Comment: You would still use an identity matrix to cover the largest NxN matrix that is contained.  Whatever rows/columns that remain you 'wrap' the identity matrix top-to-bottom or left-to-right.  Those items outside the NxN matrix will be overlaps but you are free to swap the rows within the NxN matrix to vary distribution.